# Is there a name for the "adjoint representation" for an associate algebra?

Tags: terminology, representation-theory

I have seen the notion of the adjoint representation of a lie algebra $L$ ad the map: $\text{ad}:L \to \text{End}(L)$ defined by:

$$ \text{ad:}x \mapsto [x,-]$$

My question is, is there a similar name for the "take an element to the multiplication by that element" map in an associative algebra $A$? I.e. the map $m:A \to \text{End}(A)$ defined by:
$$ m: a \mapsto a \times -$$

$m$ is therefore an algebra homomorphism, and hence should be a representation, right? I am not well versed in representation theory, so I may have gotten some concepts mixed up.

Comment: I would call that the (left) regular representation.

Answer (score 2):

It is called the (left) regular representation.